# White space changes the delimiter when running MySQL script from the shell/command prompt

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I use `MySQL innodb version 5.7.10 'MySQL Community Server (GPL)'` on a Windows machine. The following script runs fine if I run it from MySQL Workbench:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure1;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1(IN pageSize BIGINT) 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT pageSize;
END //

DELIMITER ;     -- note that there is an extra tab char here

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure2;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure2() 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table2;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

But if copy the script into *schema.sql* and run it from Windows command prompt:

```
mysql> c:\release\ver1\schema.sql
```

I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER //

This error is because of the tab char, if I remove the tab, it will run fine.

I have also tried running it from Linux shell (`MyQSL innodb version 5.7.25`) and I get the same error:

```
mysql> source /home/ubuntu/release/ver1/schema.sql
```

*Note: I have tried replacing the **tab** char (`\t`) with a couple of **white space** characters, and the white spaces are fine... it's only the tab char which changes the delimiter.*

---

I am using MySQL Workbench for the Dev Environment, but for Test and Prod Environments, I am just using MySQL from Linux Shell... this error has caught me so many times, because the scripts which have passed the Dev Environment, fails in Test and every time I have to remember to go back and remove the tabs from the script.

Is there anyway to fix this issue or configure MySQL to ignore tab char?

Comment: can you move all (both) drop procedure calls to the front so as to avoid the extra delimiter change? I see that you have a space in the `// ` delimiter, too, but it is balanced, also in the END...

Comment: Did you try to execute the script on windows the same way as on linux? Just to see, if there is any difference.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: thanks for your suggestion, I have tested on Windows Command prompt and I get the same error. Also I have noticed that it is only the tab char which causes this issue, white spaces are fine. I have updated the question.

Comment: Just curious: what happens if you add a tab after `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure2;`

Comment: My understanding is that the delimiter is changed to `;\t` char, so that next statement should run if I use `;\t`

Comment: And more curious: what happens (on Linux only) when you do `mysql < script`?

Comment: Is the code block everything in your schema.sql file?

Comment: @nbk, yes... of course `table1` and `table2` already exist in the DB

Comment: My mysql stops because it has no schema, so that i have to add one to the script, that's why i am asking.

Comment: So not using a TAB is the solution? Maybe you should configure Workbench to convert tabs to spaces (in editor). Any IDE should have this setting. Also workbench should have an export feature, will will generate a "clean" script.

Comment: @nbk, yes of course you need to run `use db-name` before the script...

Answer (score 1):

There are programs like [GrepWin](https://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html) that can easily replace characters in files. However, if you want something automated, I would recommend you setup a [webhook](https://github.com/vicenteguerra/git-deploy) and have a command to replace all tabs like below execute every time your schema is pushed.

```
sed -i.bak $'s/\t*//g' schema.sql
```